# How to control turtlesim by a publisher data sent by arduino rosserial

Tags: arduino, ros-kinetic, turtlesim, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm noob in ROS, and i used this aduino code to send Float64 data to ros

```
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

std_msgs::Float64 float_msg;

ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &float_msg);

float x = 5;

void setup()

{

  nh.initNode();

  nh.advertise(chatter);

}


void loop()
{

  float_msg.data = x;


  chatter.publish( &float_msg );

  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

then i used the following command to control turtle sent publisher data

```
rostopic pub -1 /turtle1/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[chatter, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 1.8]'
```

but it doesn't read chatter as Float64 data so it doesn't work , even i checked `rostopic info chatter` and it had float64 data type

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329400/how-to-control-turtlesim-by-a-publisher-data-sent-by-arduino-rosserial/) by [requestadepache](https://answers.ros.org/users/44320/requestadepache/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rostopic` is not the right command for republishing the content of one topic as a separate message on another topic since it does not evaluate the arguments passed ('[chatter, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 1.8]').

```
rostopic pub -1 /turtle1/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[chatter, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 1.8]'
```

The [`relay_field`](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/639) node from `topic_tools` (http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools) is more appropriate for your purpose as it provides this functionality. The command for this would be

```
rosrun topic_tools relay_field /chatter /turtle1/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist "linear:
  x: m.data
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 1.8"
```

---

Originally posted by [nkhedekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/34897/nkhedekar/) with karma: 138 on 2019-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [requestadepache](https://answers.ros.org/users/44320/requestadepache/) on 2019-07-27**:
Thanks for your help :)

**Comment by [nkhedekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/34897/nkhedekar/) on 2019-07-27**:
Happy to help :) please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to rosserial documentation :
The Arduino does not support 64-bit float datatypes. The serialization/deserialization code generated by make_library will automatically convert 64-bit floats into 32-bit datatypes, however, it should be noted that a loss of precision may occur!

---

Originally posted by [houssem trabelsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44082/houssem-trabelsi/) with karma: 21 on 2019-08-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1